# Что быстрее While или for на языке Delphi

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

Какой из двух предложенных циклов работает быстрее?

Comment: Не знаю как в Делфи, но в C++ ставишь точку останова в режиме отладки и по ЛКМ где-то есть менюшка, позволяющая отладку на ассемблере.

Comment: да, точка останова и Alt-Ctrl-C, чтобы войти в асм отладку. А про скорость циклов не стоит заморачиваться, есть поважнее вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сами по себе циклы for и while реализуются практически одинаковым набором ассемблерных инструкций.

Даже если бы там была разница в 2-3 команды, при современных скоростях процессоров это не ощутить.

Один цикл может работать медленнее другого, если у одного в вычислении условия выхода из цикла идёт вызов каких-нибудь медленных функций (например, обращение к полям визуальных компонентов, которые часто реализуются через вызов WinAPI), а у другого всё необходимое было вычислено предварительно и сохранено в локальных переменных.

Официальная документация по циклам доступна по ссылке: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Control_Loops

Comment: `у другого всё необходимое было вычислено предварительно` - для for это определено спецификацией языка `the expressions initialValue and finalValue are evaluated only once, before the loop begins.`